# Insert a value in a slice at a given index

Tags: go, slice

Given

```
array1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
array2 := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}
```

I want to insert `array2[2]` i.e `6` at `array1[1]` i.e before `3` so that `array1` becomes a slice of `{1, 6, 3, 4, 5}`. How can I do it?

Most the techniques I read online involve using the `:` operator but results in remaining elements being inserted as well. How can I append single values at an index in a slice?

Comment: Also see these useful [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#insert)

Comment: In case anyone in the future finds this via google, Golang now has a library function for this, as noted by @ufukty in their answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656249/2562033).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simple, efficient and logical way:

1. Make sure `array1` has enough capacity (length) to accomodate the new, insertable element. To do that, append a single element using the builting [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) (doesn't matter what that is, it'll get overwritten).
2. To insert an element, existing elements must be *shifted* (copied over to 1 index higher) to make room for that element, e.g. using the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) (elements you want to insert before).
3. Set the element at the proper index, using a single [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments).

In code:

```
array1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
array2 := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}

array1 = append(array1, 0)   // Step 1
copy(array1[2:], array1[1:]) // Step 2
array1[1] = array2[2]        // Step 3

fmt.Println(array1)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KaB62ANim9)):

```
[1 6 3 4 5]
```

#### Optimization in special cases

Note that in some special cases (when the slice element is big, like a big struct), it may be faster to append the last element, and then it's enough to copy 1 less elements (because the appended last element is right where it needs to be).

This is how it looks like:

```
last := len(array1) - 1
array1 = append(array1, array1[last]) // Step 1
copy(array1[2:], array1[1:last])      // Step 2
array1[1] = array2[2]                 // Step 3
```

This will result in the same slice. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YYzmwVAbrNs).

Comment: Most may know this, make sure to remember slices are just special references to arrays and in some cases, like if `array1` is a slice of a slice and the original slice is hanging around somewhere, the append overwrites the next element in the array no matter who else may be using it it. It may cause you a headache [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yelagAXPdKf).

Comment: Generous use of the word Simple

Comment: Note, the Optimization version will panic if `len(array1) == 0`. It will require additional code to test for that.

Answer (score 112):

A simple `append` is what you need:

```
a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...)
a[index] = value
```

Note: `len(a) > 0 && index < len(a)`

Should `len(a) == index`, meaning `nil` or empty slice or append after the last element:

```
a = append(a, value)
```

Inserting at the index zero for slice of `int`s:

```
a = append([]int{value}, a...)
```

---

All in one function:

```
// 0 <= index <= len(a)
func insert(a []int, index int, value int) []int {
    if len(a) == index { // nil or empty slice or after last element
        return append(a, value)
    }
    a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...) // index < len(a)
    a[index] = value
    return a
}
```

Usage:

```
    a := []int{10, 30, 40}
    a = insert(a, 1, 20)
    fmt.Println(a) // [10 20 30 40]
```

And for the OP:

```
    slice1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    slice2 := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}
    // slice1 = insert(slice1, 1, slice2[2])
    slice1 = append(slice1[:2], slice1[1:]...)
    slice1[1] = slice2[2]

    fmt.Println(slice1) // [1 6 3 4 5]
```

---

Benchmark:

```
go version
# go version go1.16.3 linux/amd64
make bench
go test -benchmem -bench . -args -n 32
# BenchmarkInsert-8      4125085  275.0 ns/op  512 B/op  1 allocs/op
# BenchmarkInsert2-8     3778551  316.0 ns/op  512 B/op  1 allocs/op

go test -benchmem -bench . -args -n 1000
# BenchmarkInsert-8       198364  5876 ns/op  16384 B/op  1 allocs/op
# BenchmarkInsert2-8      205197  7123 ns/op  16384 B/op  1 allocs/op

go test -benchmem -bench . -args -n 1000000
# BenchmarkInsert-8          643  1898436 ns/op 10002437 B/op  1 allocs/op
# BenchmarkInsert2-8         368  3248385 ns/op 10002436 B/op  1 allocs/op
```

Code:

```
func insert(a []int, index int, value int) []int {
    a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...) // Step 1+2
    a[index] = value                      // Step 3
    return a
}
func insert2(a []int, index int, value int) []int {
    last := len(a) - 1
    a = append(a, a[last])           // Step 1
    copy(a[index+1:], a[index:last]) // Step 2
    a[index] = value                 // Step 3
    return a
}
func BenchmarkInsert(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r = insert(a, 2, 42)
    }
}
func BenchmarkInsert2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        r = insert2(a, 2, 42)
    }
}

var (
    n    = flag.Int("n", 32, "buffer length")
    a, r []int
)

// We use TestMain to set up the buffer.
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    flag.Parse()
    a = make([]int, *n)
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

You may combine the **two** first steps to **one**; by using:

```
    a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...)
```

1. This makes sure the array has enough capacity to accommodate the new element.
2. This copies all required elements to one index higher to make room for the new element.
3. Set the element at the index, using a single assignment: `a[index] = value`

Which is more efficient, according to the benchmarks.

---

Should you need to insert at `index > cap(a)` (note: **untested code**) - [try it on the The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zlRwlGZk2bc):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func insert(a []int, index int, value int) []int {
    n := len(a)
    if index < 0 {
        index = (index%n + n) % n
    }
    switch {
    case index == n: // nil or empty slice or after last element
        return append(a, value)

    case index < n: // index < len(a)
        a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...)
        a[index] = value
        return a

    case index < cap(a): // index > len(a)
        a = a[:index+1]
        for i := n; i < index; i++ {
            a[i] = 0
        }
        a[index] = value
        return a

    default:
        b := make([]int, index+1) // malloc
        if n > 0 {
            copy(b, a)
        }
        b[index] = value
        return b
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    a = a[:5]
    fmt.Println(insert(a, 7, 70)) // [0 1 2 3 4 0 0 70]

    a = []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    a = a[:4]
    fmt.Println(insert(a, 5, 50)) // [0 1 2 3 0 50]

    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 50), 10, 10)) // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10]

    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1}, -1, 10))       // [10 1]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -2, 10)) // [1 10 2 3]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -1, 10)) // [1 2 10 3]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -4, 10)) // [1 2 10 3]

    fmt.Println(insert(nil, 0, 0))       // [0]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{}, 0, 0))   // [0]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1}, 1, 10)) // [1 10]

    fmt.Println(insert(nil, 5, 50)) // [0 0 0 0 0 50]

    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 1, 10)) // [0 10]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 2, 20)) // [0 0 20]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 3, 30)) // [0 0 0 30]

    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10, 20, 30}, 5, 50)) // [0 10 20 30 0 50]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0}, 5, 50))             // [0 0 0 0 0 50]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10}, 0, 0))          // [0 0 10]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10}, 1, 5))          // [0 5 10]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 5, 50), 0, 0))    // [0 0 0 0 0 0]
}
```

---

Using generics  (note: **untested code**) - [try it on the The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dS9bHFuqCbI):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func insert[T any](a []T, index int, value T) []T {
    n := len(a)
    if index < 0 {
        index = (index%n + n) % n
    }
    switch {
    case index == n: // nil or empty slice or after last element
        return append(a, value)

    case index < n: // index < len(a)
        a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...)
        a[index] = value
        return a

    case index < cap(a): // index > len(a)
        a = a[:index+1]
        var zero T
        for i := n; i < index; i++ {
            a[i] = zero
        }
        a[index] = value
        return a

    default:
        b := make([]T, index+1) // malloc
        if n > 0 {
            copy(b, a)
        }
        b[index] = value
        return b
    }
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    a = a[:5]
    fmt.Println(insert(a, 7, 70)) // [0 1 2 3 4 0 0 70]

    a = []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    a = a[:4]
    fmt.Println(insert(a, 5, 50)) // [0 1 2 3 0 50]

    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 50), 10, 10)) // [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10]

    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1}, -1, 10))       // [10 1]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -2, 10)) // [1 10 2 3]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -1, 10)) // [1 2 10 3]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1, 2, 3}, -4, 10)) // [1 2 10 3]

    fmt.Println(insert(nil, 0, 0))       // [0]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{}, 0, 0))   // [0]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{1}, 1, 10)) // [1 10]

    fmt.Println(insert(nil, 5, 50)) // [0 0 0 0 0 50]

    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 1, 10)) // [0 10]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 2, 20)) // [0 0 20]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 0, 1), 3, 30)) // [0 0 0 30]

    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10, 20, 30}, 5, 50)) // [0 10 20 30 0 50]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0}, 5, 50))             // [0 0 0 0 0 50]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10}, 0, 0))          // [0 0 10]
    fmt.Println(insert([]int{0, 10}, 1, 5))          // [0 5 10]
    fmt.Println(insert(make([]int, 5, 50), 0, 0))    // [0 0 0 0 0 0]
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. It is the most succinct solution and it comes with benchmarks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is by design, but neither `insert` nor `insert2` can be used to append an item at the end of the slice. Trying to do so generates a panic: https://go.dev/play/p/zW32Fbf1Nxi

Comment: @DanielYankowsky You need to run benchmark in a file named `main_test.go` and for the main only use the "All in one function" - and please read the top section.

Comment: @wasmup Yes, I saw that you had a note about inserting into a nil slice or at the length of the slice, but it wasn't clear to me what that note was trying to say. I guess you were saying "is not supported". That seems like a pretty glaring limitation.

Comment: @DanielYankowsky Check the generics version at the end of this new edit, I hope this helps. [Run it](https://go.dev/play/p/dS9bHFuqCbI)

Answer (score 12):

I found the question setup pretty tricky to follow.

Rephrased, they want to insert an element. Here we have an array where it's missing the element `3` and we want to insert it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 4, 5, 6}
    b := 3

    // Make space in the array for a new element. You can assign it any value.
    a = append(a, 0)   
    fmt.Println(a)

    // Copy over elements sourced from index 2, into elements starting at index 3.
    copy(a[3:], a[2:])  
    fmt.Println(a)

    a[2] = b         
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of icza answer.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the answers are old and there is a official `slices.Insert` function.

[Docs](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Insert)

Its header is:

```golang
func Insert[S ~[]E, E any](s S, i int, v ...E) S
```

Your use case:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    array1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    array2 := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}

    array1 = slices.Insert(array1, 1, array2[2])
    fmt.Println(array1) // prints: [1 6 3 4 5]
}
```

Note that it returns the new slice, not modifies the input parameter in-place.

You can see how it is implemented [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.0:src/slices/slices.go;l=132). It also takes `cap` of slice into considiration and makes appropriate move if the new `len` exceeds the current `cap`.

Comment: This is really nice and succinct. However, when I tried benchmarking a function in one of my applications using this I found that it was quite a bit slower (and used one extra allocation) than the type of solution shown by @NoAngel here (i.e. making a new slice of the right size and then using copies). I can't see why this should be the case. From this evidence (and I'll admit that I might be misinterpreting my benchmarking) it looks like growing a slice with append is more expensive than creating a new one with make, even though the former should only allocate if the capacity is too small.

Comment: @jcquokka88 Can you edit my answer and add your benchmarks? I believe people would want to be informed about performance.

Comment: Actually I think my benchmarking wasn't set up correctly and I was inadvertently only benchmarking a case of inserting one element in the middle of a slice of two. When I fixed the benchmark to do a wider range of inserts on different-sized slices then the slices.Insert function was a winner. I think the slices packages is really good and makes my code much more readable as well.

Answer (score 3):

extending the answer from @Volker, i put the answer here https://play.golang.org/p/3Hla2y2ava too if you want to test it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    array1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}
    array2 := []int{2, 4, 6, 8}
    temp := append([]int{array2[2]}, array1[1:]...)
    array1 = append(array1[:1], temp...)
    fmt.Println(array1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution worked for me

```
func insert(a []int, c int, i int) []int {
    return append(a[:i], append([]int{c}, a[i:]...)...)
}
```

You can make it more general via empty interfaces

```
func insert(a []interface{}, c interface{}, i int) []interface{} {
    return append(a[:i], append([]interface{}{c}, a[i:]...)...)
}
```

Comment: plus'd to support answerer, however, i do not endorse to recommend that solution. imho, the OP question is hardly factorized in a function that satisfies as many requirements as the std append builtin function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is it optimal or not, but this piece of code works for me:

```
func sliceins(arr []int, pos int, elem int) []int { //insert element before pos in slice. if pos >= len(arr) insert into tail
    if pos < 0 {
        pos = 0
    } else if pos >= len(arr) {
        pos = len(arr)
    }
    out := make([]int, len(arr)+1)
    copy(out[:pos], arr[:pos])
    out[pos] = elem
    copy(out[pos+1:], arr[pos:])
    return out
}
```

In Your case just call

```
sliceins(array1, 1, array2[2])
```

Comment: code above can be easily changed to support another type or 2D array

Comment: Looks good, but I'd probably avoid that if statement at the top and let it panic if you pass in invalid indexes, to conform to how regular slices behave.

Answer (score 1):

Based on icza's post i wrote a function to shift the slice / array which I want to share with you:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "c", "d"}
    shiftArray(&s, 1, "b")
    fmt.Println(s)

}

func shiftArray(array *[]string, position int, value string) {
    //  extend array by one
    *array = append(*array, "")

    // shift values
    copy((*array)[position+1:], (*array)[position:])

    // insert value
    (*array)[position] = value
}
```

Comment: It'd be more idiomatic Go to return the array rather than using a pointer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here a one-liner:

```
append(array1[:1], append(array2[2:3], array1[1:]...)...)
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/xqXpkIFo7Z6)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question in other thread. Anyway I used the following methods to play with slices and index:

```
func insertInt(array []int, value int, index int) []int {
    return append(array[:index], append([]int{value}, array[index:]...)...)
}

func removeInt(array []int, index int) []int {
    return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}

func moveInt(array []int, srcIndex int, dstIndex int) []int {
    value := array[srcIndex]
    return insertInt(removeInt(array, srcIndex), value, dstIndex)
}
```

You can play with it here:

https://play.golang.org/p/Sfu1VsySieS

I hope it'll help you

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
append(append(slice[:i], elem), slice[i:]...)
```

Comment: This one won't work because the internal append writes over the i'th element so the outer append then duplicates it into the (i+1)th element, which you don't want (that is, slice[i] no longer has the value you want in the arguments for the outer append).

Answer (score 0):

I found it's hard to wrap my head around `a = append(a[:index+1], a[index:]...)`
Also as @lieblos warned, working on the original slice is tricky.

Here is an easier solution, though not memory efficient:

```
  var array3 []int
  array3 = append(array3, array1[:1]...)
  array3 = append(array3, array2[2])
  array3 = append(array3, array1[1:]...)
  array1 = array3
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rni5hgB0JNt