# how to insert value in first slice index in golang

Tags: arrays, go, struct

i have an struct & array slice

```golang
type Book struct {
    bookName string
    category string
    creator  string
}

var books = []Book{
    {bookName: "study go", category: "programming", creator: "steve"},
    {bookName: "study html", category: "programming", creator: "jobs"},
}

func main() {

//how to add data to index[0] or front of books

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a value in a slice at a given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128016/insert-a-value-in-a-slice-at-a-given-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func test() {
    books = append([]Book{{
        bookName: "study c++",
        category: "programing",
        creator:  "tmp",
    }}, books...)
    fmt.Println(books)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clarified. I have tried to give you an answer. I combined the first index in the `books` variable with other data in the `new` variable.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Book struct {
    bookName string
    category string
    creator  string
}

func main() {
    var books = []Book{
        {bookName: "study go", category: "programming", creator: "steve"},
        {bookName: "study html", category: "programming", creator: "jobs"},
    }
    var new = []Book{
        {bookName: "study css", category: "Styling", creator: "john"},
    }
    new = append(books[0:2], new[0])
    fmt.Println(new)
}
```

**Result**

```
[{study go programming steve} {study html programming jobs} {study css Styling john}]
```

Comment: why {bookName: "study html", category: "programming", creator: "jobs"} deleted?
i want result to

[ {study css Styling john}{study go programming steve}{study html programming steve}]

Comment: @ryandipratamapurba You said that you just want index[0] that is the first one. Now I updated the code including all of them.